# what is @Protected in reactjs Mobx?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I believe [this](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/object.html) is the MobX official documentation, but it does not mention @Protected.
Here is where @Protected is used:
[Mobx Inject, Observer and HoC together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906823/mobx-inject-observer-and-hoc-together)

What is @Protected? Is there any documentation for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to **Protractor**, which is a testing framework for Angular and React. Here are some links explaining it:

- [End-to-end testing with protractor for nonangular applications using
  modern ES6 javascript syntax](https://medium.com/@marcelmokos/end-to-end-testing-with-protractor-using-modern-javascript-syntax-44e5121c2e03)
- [Testing React apps with Protractor](http://www.joelotter.com/2015/04/18/protractor-reactjs.html)